# fread is reading all the data in file but not saving it in a as definition of structure

Tags: c, structure, fread

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
typedef struct cr{
char name[20];
int credit;
}cr;



void main(){

 int i ;
 FILE *fp;
 cr *ptr;
 cr data[20];
 clrscr();

 ptr=data;


 fp=fopen("c:\\new\\damn.txt","rb");
 fread(ptr,sizeof(cr),1,fp);
 printf("%s\n",ptr->name);






 getch();
 }
```

the file damn.txt has a string and an int with spaces in between them
content : " prateek 20"

but when i read this file with fread and then when i am printing the contents of the structure using %s and %d , i found out that all the content is stored in structure only in name array and nothing is stored in credit ? what is happening ?how can i read the structure in the format of sturcture ? and save it in the variables respectively ?why 20 is not storing in credit ?

Comment: Because `fread` (a) does not magically zero-terminate strings, and (b) does not magically convert ASCII (or any other encoding) to integers. Oh and (c) it doesn't truncate fields on spaces either. You may want to look to `fscanf`.

Answer (score 0):

I always do

```
memset(cr, 0, 20);
fread(pt,19,1,fp);
```

So you always have a terminating null at the end